# Selecting column values from one table, where column values are stored in another table

Tags: sql

I want to make use of a database table in order to build up my query, what to select from multiple tables. I have done this in the below table ColumnsInfo. It holds the table name and a column to select from that table. Problem is I don't know how to build up the query to query ColumnsInfo to in turn query the different tables.

```
  TableName    ColumnName
    t1             info1
    t1             info2
    t1             info3
    t2             info1
    t2             info2
    t2             info3
```

Say that I have 2 tables, **t1,t2** and a third table **columnInfo** stated above. Now I want to `select info1,info2,info3 from t1 union info1,info2,info3 from t2` using the table above. How can I do that?

I want to append tablename to ColumnName in the query

```
select info1 as tablename-info1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which database are you working with? It needs to be a query? I dont think its possible to build dynamic sql within a query

Comment: You might want to look at something like this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/155d8dcf-03a4-4b68-88db-f1ce49f5170a/how-do-i-use-a-variable-to-specify-the-column-name-in-a-select-statement?forum=transactsql